# Auto click button inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, automation

I'm trying to automate the join event, it's a groove page with a default form. I need to skip "join button" and automatically redirect people to another page.

The only way is to trigger an auto click using js.

But it's not working in my case

```
function myFunction() { 
    var data = document.getElementById("count_id").value;
    var  datacount = (parseInt(data) + 1);
    document.getElementById("count_id").value = datacount;  
    document.getElementById("clickbutton").value = "Clicked";
}

setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("clickbutton").click(); 
}, 3000);
```

This code works well, but the button is inside an iframe, and it is added using inspect element. Using `document.getElementsByClassName` I get the error `document.getElementsByClassName(...).click is not a function`

Comment: Are you trying to access a button from inside the iframe? If so, then this might not be possible due to security features.

Comment: Well yes, button is inside iframe

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
`document.getElementById('iFrameId').contentDocument.getElementById('clickbutton').click()`

Comment: This is structure '<iframe src=''><button class="join-button"></button></iframe>'  [link](https://riannascipio.groovepages.com/tight/tight-webinar-page-11)